# Using JSoup to Parse a document and remove divs with specific IDs and Classes

Tags: java, jsoup

Even though it is simple and similar questions have already been asked,  I am somehow not able to get through it.

```
public static Document removeDiv(Document document){

    document.getElementById("Wrapper_FixedWidth_Footer").remove();
    document.getElementById("u01").remove();

   return document;
}`
```

Please take the following document as an input to the method.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.oracle.com/storage/san/fs1/index.html").ignoreHttpErrors(true).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0").timeout(0).get();
```

More specifically I do not want to include the header and the footer. (I do not want the links that are under the corresponding divs of the header and the footer of this document)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. It seems there was some issue with the crawler and  conditions that I was checking at some other part of the code.